# is it possible to create a web site with expression web to be deployed on a non asp.net host?

Tags: expression-web

I want to create a very sinple web site with expression web but I want to be able to deploy it on a non asp.net server. Is this possible or I have to use a asp.net host?

The pages just display images and text. I do not need to do anything with the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you develop a site in Expression web that DOESN'T use ASP.NET, you could publish it on a non-.NET webserver. Expression Web can be used for PHP, ASP, ASP.NET or just plain HTML, the server requirements will be accordingly.